# Why does PHP DateTime::setTime causes weird behavior of strtotime?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I am trying to shift the date for serveral times and correct its time. I can't find reason why the date don't want to change after \DateTime::setTime.

```
$now = new \DateTime();

$nextFriday = new \DateTime('@' . strtotime('next friday', $now->getTimestamp()));
```

I get: 2019-03-21 23:00:00.0 +00:00

```
$nextFriday->setTime(12, 30);
```

I get: 2019-03-21 12:30:00.0 +00:00

```
$nextNextFriday = new \DateTime('@' . strtotime('next friday', $nextFriday->getTimestamp()));
```

And now, what is going on:

2019-03-21 23:00:00.0 +00:00

Comment: Why are you using `strtotime()` here at all?

Comment: @JohnConde I need to generate date from weekday name ('next friday'). But anyway - that what is going on is weird as hell. Some kind of sorcery.

Comment: Quite honestly, I simply wouldn't count on whatever automagic is going on in `strtotime` at all. It's pretty trivial to check what day of the week a `DateTime` object has and add a few days to it as appropriate. And to go from one Friday to the next Friday doesn't require any `"next friday"` magic – just add 7 days!

Comment: @deceze Is it? How do You want trivially get any next weekday of current DateTime?

Comment: You can get the weekday as a number from 0 to 6… it’s a tiny bit of math to figure out the difference between that and the next Friday.

Comment: @deceze appreciate that, but still, when you have large amount of weekdays as strings and you have to count this DateTime interval dynamically you just want to use what is available in stable version of what you use and do not invent wheel again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason why time is being reset is that relative PHP date modifier `'next ...'` reset time always to actually "beginning of next ...".

Why you're getting `23:00:00+00:00` is probably because of different timezones set on server vs your system (assuming local development).

If you need to go relative to date use:

```php
<?php

$now = new \DateTime();

$nextFriday = clone $now;

$nextFriday->modify('next friday');
// also here time will be 00:00:00

$nextFriday->setTime(12,30);

var_dump($nextFriday);
// "2019-03-22 12:30:00.000000"
```